# Hyperledger Fabric deploy on VMs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm new to hyperledger fabric.

I am just following up on this [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html) to deploy on one VM in GCP, now I got confused.

1. Does the peer mean one VM?
2. How to write the config file for many VMs?
3. If the above question is true, how do I config them to communicate those VMs to become a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network?

Should I edit /etc/hosts this file to know what hostname on what VM?

---

Update:

I've been trying to create a custom network. And I always got this error

```
Fatal error when initializing core config : error when reading core config file: Config File "core" Not Found in "[/etc/hyperledger/peercfg]"
```

Here is my script

```
ROOTDIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)
export PATH=${ROOTDIR}/../bin:${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/configtx
export VERBOSE=false

pushd ${ROOTDIR} > /dev/null
trap "popd > /dev/null" EXIT

cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org1.yaml --output="organizations"



: ${CONTAINER_CLI:="docker"}
: ${CONTAINER_CLI_COMPOSE:="${CONTAINER_CLI}-compose"}

COMPOSE_FILE_BASE=compose-test-net.yaml


SOCK="${DOCKER_HOST:-/var/run/docker.sock}"
DOCKER_SOCK="${SOCK##unix://}"
COMPOSE_FILES="-f compose/${COMPOSE_FILE_BASE} -f compose/${CONTAINER_CLI}/${CONTAINER_CLI}-${COMPOSE_FILE_BASE}"
DOCKER_SOCK="${DOCKER_SOCK}" ${CONTAINER_CLI_COMPOSE} ${COMPOSE_FILES} up -d 2>&1
$CONTAINER_CLI ps -a

echo "${DOCKER_SOCK}" ${CONTAINER_CLI_COMPOSE} ${COMPOSE_FILES} up -d 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Docker container is the recommended way to run Hyperledger peer, orderer etc, although it is possible to run components natively without docker. The sample network provided in official documentation uses multiple docker containers in a single host machine for testing purpose. In a production n/w, all these components will be in different vm instances.
2. Configuration can be provided either in yaml file or as environment variables. [Deploy peers and ordering nodes](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deployment_guide_overview.html#step-five-deploy-peers-and-ordering-nodes)
3. This needs configuration change at multiple levels like channel configuration(configtx.yaml), orderer and peer configuration, gossip configuration, hostname change in the certificates of peer,orderer etc. An overview is available in [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deployment_guide_overview.html#step-five-deploy-peers-and-ordering-nodes). Since you are new to fabric, I would recommend to have a look at the sample n/w provided in [fabric-samples](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deployment_guide_overview.html#step-five-deploy-peers-and-ordering-nodes) before designing your n/w.

Comment: I just follow up on the test-network docs and look into all files, I don't quite understand what the minimize step and files to create a network. For example, 2 peer, 1 org, 1 channel, 1 order, and it would be 3 VMs (2 peers, 1 order) in the network.

Comment: Creating a custom network needs some expertise on fabric. You have to generate the crypto materials for the nodes,  write the docker compose files for the nodes and have to write the scripts for creating channel , deploying chaincode etc. The sample network script is doing all this  [behind the scenes](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html#what-s-happening-behind-the-scenes). Sample network is having 2 peer organizations having a single peer each and one orderer organization. You may try editing those scripts and compose files to  begin with.

Comment: Hi @Basil K Y, I just update the question. could you help me to figure it out?

Comment: This error comes because peer is unable to find core.yaml in specified location(/etc/hyperledger/peercfg). Please raise separate stackoverflow post for different issues.